# AWS: how to manage email

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have domain on Godaddy. I will migrate dns for this domain from godaddy to AWS. However, AWS seems to be not the best service to use email (send and receive message like in gmail).

I'm going to use 2 emails: support@example.com and contact@example.com. one of them I will use to send notifications from app on AWS. Second one, I want to use like typical email for daily personal duties.

What solution you can recommend me?

Set me record on AWS route 53 after migration to some another service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [AWS Simple Email Service](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/) (SES) to send notifications programmatically from applications using AWS SDK.

[Receiving email](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/setup-email-receiving-pipeline/) with SES is also supported, and you can use it to trigger other AWS services, such as Lambda or SNS. In addition, SES can forward received messages to [Amazon WorkMail](https://aws.amazon.com/workmail/) which is an email client you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In case if you dont want to pay to Amazon WorkMail since it will cost little more , you can use aws s3 to receive your daily mails.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/ses/receiving-email-with-amazon-ses/